# for loop of HTTP POST in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, http, post

I am doing multiple HTTP POST to a REST web service that I created. This POST will then translate to an INSERT to a table in the database. The table has a column called ROUTE_ORDER (auto-incremented). This column preserves the order in which the POST was coming in (useful for some other parts of my application), it's an int which has values of 1,2,3.. etc.

I tried to execute the HTTP POST using CURL of the entries one by one and it works perfectly fine. However I have a loop inside my XCode project, which iterates through an array an do a POST based on the content in the array and the order messed up. Below is the code:

```
for (Location * loc in [self.data objectForKey:@"route"])
         [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] postObject:loc delegate:self];
```

So my idea is to put a time interval between each iteration of the POST, so that the previous POST finishes first and then goes to the next one and therefore the ORDER is preserved. Question is how can I do this in objective-C? Is this even the problem?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would suggest, rather than making one request (which can potentially be really large (not sure about your scenario), you can still make multiple requests, but have an order parameter in the request which tells the server what the actual order of the request is, so the server can do behave accordingly

Comment: that is true the data could possible grow really large... giving an order parameter is a good way too

Comment: see comments on my answer for an explanation of why this is unwise.

Comment: @kevboh once again, (even though the OP said nothing about request size), do you really think its a good idea to send huge loads in one request?

Comment: Did you read the question? It's an array of location objects. Do you understand how many locations would be required to create "huge loads"? In the event there are millions of points, wouldn't it be better to send one request and let optimized fragmentation libraries handle it than send one million requests? Do you understand how networks work?

Comment: i said, regardless of what the OP said dude..do you still think its a good idea?

Comment: Yes. That is why I answered it, and have been carrying on this inane argument with you. Clearly you (mistakenly) believe otherwise.

Comment: I actually liked Daniel's suggestion the most.. it suits with my needs really well. I was thinking of the back end too much that I want to have a very thin client.. but if the client just needs to count order, I don't think that's a lot of work, even if it's from 0 to 100k

Comment: Suit yourself... hammering your own server with many ordered requests is a pointless endeavor. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallacies_of_Distributed_Computing

Comment: To be realistic, the best approach here is a middle ground between  this and what kev said, I still dont think one should upload many  megabytes/gigabytes of data to a web service in one shot, however if the data is small, say you have a billion chunks of 10 bytes each, i would def be linking a good amount of those together for one request, instead of making a billion requests...

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend adding an NSOperationQueue to your project (it looks like within the rkobject singleton) with a maximum number of connections set to 1.  Then, as you issue your service calls from inside your loop, you're really just adding another operation to the queue.  The queue will manage iterating through each operation, one at a time, until all have completed.  You could also identify hard dependencies by adding the addDependency method after adding your operation to the queue.

Answer (score 0):

Create a New class which will have a queue (holder for your post requests data) object and a timer.
Add all your request to queue.

Add your data whenever you want to queue then start the timer (can be used for timeout purpose),when you receive data from server immediately check your queue for next server request.

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is that you're relying on a network connection to preserve ordering. Instead of making a series of requests, make a single request that contains the data you want to POST in the order you want it to be inserted. Then edit your backend to accept this format. This way you make one request no matter what (faster, more reliable) and the data is always properly ordered.

Comment: good idea! just wondering how to push an NSArray to a HTTP Body in iPhone

Comment: A single request may be too big and unfeasible...i would suggest have  each request tell the server the actual order it should be in, since it seem s that the client already knowns it..

Comment: Sweet downvote, bro. A network is a fundamentally unreliable resource. Plus, how would a single request be too big but a thousand tiny ones be okay?

Comment: Equinox: you should consider structuring your http body using xml or JSON. JSON in particular has great support for arrays/dictionaries, and TouchJSON (https://github.com/TouchCode/TouchJSON) is an awesome library for generating/parsing it.

Comment: You think sending a large chunk of data (hundreds of MBs) in one request is a good idea?

Comment: Where did OP say hundreds of MBs? An array of location data would have to be in the millions to reach hundreds of MBs in size.

Comment: The OP said nothing about data size...so you cant assume either way

Comment: He said it's an array of Location objects and that he was able to iterate through them by hand... that's a pretty sweet hint.

Comment: And how do you know that array of objects wont grow very large potentially?